# members of a class known at any point inside class

Tags: c++

I always thought that if I declare member of a class inside class this member is known at the entire scope of a class that is:

```
 class X
{
public:
    X(int a) :v_(a)
    {}
private:
    int v_;//even though v_ is declared here I'm using it in ctor which is above this line
};
```

So that makes sense to me.

Anyhow this doesn't because I'm getting error that `v_` isn't known

```
class X
{
public:
    X(decltype(v_) a) :v_(a)//error on this line, compiler doesn't know v_
    {}
private:
    int v_;
};
```

Would be glad to learn why.

I'm using intel compiler v14 SP1

Thank you.

Comment: The reversed form works: http://ideone.com/BcU6Hb

Comment: looks like a bug with decltype. Did u try moving the int v_ to the before the decltype

Comment: @pm100 on gcc 4.8.2 the same error generated and declaration of `v_` before ctor fixes the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **3.3.7 Class scope**
>
> **1** The following rules describe the scope of names declared in classes.
>
> 1) The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following
>   the name’s point of declaration, but also of all function bodies, brace-or-equal-initializers of non-static
>   data members, and default arguments in that class (including such things in nested classes).
>
> ...

That means that you can use `v_` in function bodies, constructor initializer lists and default arguments. You are not allowed to use `v_` in parameter declarations the way you used it in your code.

For example, this shall compile

```
class X
{
public:
    X(int a = decltype(v_)()) : v_(a)
    {}
private:
    int v_;
};
```

but not the second example in your original post.

Comment: Beat me :). I was almost copy-pasting the same statement as edit to my answer:) Good job. The working example is a wellcome extra: your answer is going to be accepted soon ;)

Comment: Is it allowed other way around, when v_ declared before ctor?

Comment: "not only of the declarative region following the name’s point of declaration" so at least that region is valid (so when v_ declared before).

You should note that if later someone touch your code for example by moving members around for doing "cache optimization" it could make your code to not compile (so put a comment beside the variable "Optimizers don't move this member around" or something equivalent :D )

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles with Clang.

Reading C++11 specifications you are not allowed to declare the variable after it is being used as function/constructor parameter.

Comment: Does not compile on gcc 4.8.2

Comment: sorry, used GCC 4.10, anyway on clang it compiles fine ^^ I assume clang. You can test a plenty of compilers with gccgodbolt. On GCC 4.9 it does not compile..

Comment: * I assume clang is correct anyway I'm reading spec to find out wich compiler is correct and wich one is lying

Comment: there is nothing to sorry about, just mentioned that it does not compile on this version.

Answer (score -1):

In many cases classes including function signatures will be defined in headers, but function bodies in cpp files. Since the header will have been read by the compiler at the start of reading the cpp file, this problem does usually not occur. But indeed, C++ compilers don't look ahead.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean by "look ahead", but the entire class has to be seen as a colmpletely defined type in function bodies and constructor initializer lists, regardless of where they are defined. So, for that purpose the compiler is required to look ahead.

Comment: What I mean I that members should be defined first and used only after that.

Comment: Well, the language does not have such requirement in some contexts. For example, in member function bodies members can be used *before* they are defined.